# In SQL, how to resolve transitive set memberships?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given this table of IDs:

```
╔═══════╤═══════╗
║ tid_1 │ tid_2 ║
╠═══════╪═══════╣
║     1 │     2 ║
║     1 │     9 ║
║     1 │    10 ║
║     2 │     9 ║
║     2 │    10 ║
║     3 │     4 ║
║     9 │    10 ║
║     9 │    12 ║
║     9 │    14 ║
║    12 │    14 ║
╚═══════╧═══════╝
```

and assuming that each row has labels of sets that are considered equivalent, how can I (in PostgreSQL) find the transitive set of equivalences?

In other words, I know that the stuff in box 14 can be thrown together with
the stuff in box 12; the stuff in box 12 with the stuff in box 9; and box 9,
in turn, is no different than the stuff in boxes 2 and 1.

I then want to go and assign a new set ID (e.g. using the smallest ID from the
transitive group) so i get

```
╔═══════╤═══════╗
║   tid │   sid ║
╠═══════╪═══════╣
║     1 │     1 ║
║     2 │     1 ║
║     3 │     3 ║
║     4 │     3 ║
║     9 │     1 ║
║    10 │     1 ║
║    12 │     1 ║
║    14 │     1 ║
╚═══════╧═══════╝
```

I've managed to come up to this point, which I belive is part of the solution:

```
create view transitive_closure as (
  with recursive containment as ( select
    p1.tid_1                          as tid_1,
    p1.tid_2                          as tid_2,
    array[ p1.tid_1 ]                 as chain,
    false                             as is_cyclic
  from links                          as p1
union all
select distinct
    p2.tid_1                          as tid_1,
    p2.tid_2                          as tid_2,
    tc.chain || p2.tid_1              as chain,
    p2.tid_2 = any( chain )           as is_cyclic
  from links as p2
  join containment as tc on ( p2.tid_1 = tc.tid_2 )
  )
select distinct tid_1, tid_3 as tid_2 from containment );
```

Comment: Please have a look at this blog post - I think it would be helpful https://thesqlserverdeveloper.blogspot.com/2018/04/building-flat-hierarchy-out-of.html?view=magazine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you are very close you just need to check for and carry through in your recursive query the lowest tid, limit the first half of the recursive query to the root nodes, use the is_cyclic check as a stop condition in the second half, and finally output a union of the tid_1 and tid_2 columns along with the sid:

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e28ff/3)**:

```
with recursive containment as ( 
  select p1.tid_1 as tid_1,
         p1.tid_2 as tid_2,
         case when p1.tid_1 < p1.tid_2
              then p1.tid_1
              else p1.tid_2
          end sid,
          array[ p1.tid_1 ] as chain,
          false as is_cyclic
  from links as p1
 where not exists (select 1 from links l where l.tid_2 = p1.tid_1)
union all
  select p2.tid_1 as tid_1,
         p2.tid_2 as tid_2,
         case when tc.sid < p2.tid_1
               and tc.sid < p2.tid_2
              then tc.sid
              when p2.tid_1 < p2.tid_2
              then p2.tid_1
              else p2.tid_2
         end sid,
         tc.chain || p2.tid_1 as chain,
         p2.tid_2 = any( chain ) as is_cyclic
    from links as p2
    join containment as tc on ( p2.tid_1 = tc.tid_2 )
   where not tc.is_cyclic
)
select tid_1, sid from containment
union
select tid_2, sid from containment
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e28ff/3/0)**:

```
| tid_1 | sid |
|-------|-----|
|     1 |   1 |
|     2 |   1 |
|     3 |   3 |
|     4 |   3 |
|     9 |   1 |
|    10 |   1 |
|    12 |   1 |
|    14 |   1 |
```